# Samsung Galaxy Player 5 Bootloop

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-player

I have a Samsung Galaxy Player 5 (US Edition) that is stuck in an infinite boot loop (Hangs at the Samsung logo). The device was running stock Android 2.3.5 with no modifications of any kind. The device was working fine and I restart the device and it has been in a boot loop since.

Is there a way that I can recover my photos from the device? I am still able to access download and recovery mode. I am also able to interface with the device via ADB. I've admittedly little experience with Android, but I've read online about the possibility of installing custom kernels using Odin while still retaining data.

If there is any additional information that I can provide, please let me know. I appreciate the help!